# Better way to re-order Django form errors?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Is there a better, more "Django-istic", way to put Django form error messages in a particular order than the technique shown below?  I have a form with ten fields in it.  If the user doesn't fill out a required field or if they enter invalid data, I iterate through the form's error fields which I've put in a custom error list by displaying a red "x" and the error message(s) at the top and a red "x" next to the invalid field(s) below:

```
{# template.html #}
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {# Non-field errors removed for clarity #}

    {# Iterate through error messages in custom ordered error list #}
    {% for error_message in ordered_error_list %}
        <img src='/static/img/red_x.png' alt='Error'></img>
        &nbsp;{{ error_message }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br />
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <img src='/static/img/red_x.png' alt='Error'></img>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {# Hidden fields removed for clarity #}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Continue" /></p>
</form>
```

Here's my view and helper function:

```
# views.py
def create_member_profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateMemberProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process form data and redirect to next page...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('review-member-profile'))
        # Before I re-POST the form and display the errors, I'll put the errors in order
        else:
            ordered_error_list = put_member_profile_errors_in_order(form)
    else:
        form = CreateMemberProfileForm()
    return render_to_response(template, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def put_member_profile_errors_in_order(form):
    errors_in_order = []  # List
    for error in form['field_1'].errors:
        errors_in_order.append(error)
    for error in form['field_2'].errors:
        errors_in_order.append(error)
    for error in form['field_3'].errors:
        errors_in_order.append(error)
    # ...
    for error in form['field_10'].errors:
        errors_in_order.append(error)
    return errors_in_order
```

The reason this all seems necessary is that form.errors is a dictionary and Python dictionaries, by definition, are unordered.  However, as I said, I want any error messages at the top to be displayed in the same order as the form fields they refer to.  I couldn't find any form.errors attributes that would allow me to re-order the form errors.  I don't like the "for error in form[]" blocks but they seem to be required if I want to strip the HTML  tag from the beginning of each error.  Also note that I'm not checking for errors by putting each "for" loop inside an "if form['field'].errors" block because omitting this doesn't make a difference and I want this code to run as fast as possible.

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Why not just display it next to each element?

Comment: Because this is going to be a "mobile first" website.  I'm designing it to be viewed primarily on mobile phones, and the typical phone screen isn't wide enough.  I could put the errors below the form fields but then user would have to scroll all the way down the page to see if there were any errors. I prefer having all the errors at the top.

Comment: Or you could highlight the first element that throws an error

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Same idea s you are using (two for loops).

```
<!-- near the top -->
<tr>
{% for field in form %}
    <td>{{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field.errors }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>

<!-- your form -->
{% for field in form %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ field.label_tag }}:</td>
    <td>
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.help_text }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Format this as you wish, but I think that kind of gives you an idea. You can also customize the error messages in your form clean:

```
from django import forms

YourForm(forms.Form):
    ....
    def field_clean(self):  # or use clean(self) for multiple fields
        ....
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Your custom error')
    ....
```

More on [form field validation from Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).